# when this function is called second time the child divs are creating again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

```
 function sort(type) {

//EMPTY FUNCTION IS CALLED HERE FOR REMOVING ALL PREVIOUSLY CREATED    CHILD DIVS

$("#parentDiv").empty();
$.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2", ({ Search }) => {   
    Search.sort((a, b) => a[type] > b[type]);
    console.log(`Sorted by: ${type}`);
    console.log("movies are displayed!!");
    var i;
```

Loop starts here for creating div elements.

```
    for(i=0;i<Search.length;i++){
    var title=Search[i].Title;
    var year=Search[i].Year;
```

parent div which contains child divs in which h2's and p's are present.

```
    var parentDiv=document.createElement("div");
    parentDiv.setAttribute("id","parentDiv");
    parentDiv.setAttribute("id","childDiv");
```

child div and h2's and p's making and appending to child div starts here

```
    var childDiv=document.createElement("div");
    var movieElement=document.createElement("h2");
    movieElement.setAttribute("id","moviename");
    var yearElement=document.createElement("p");
    yearElement.setAttribute("id","year");
    childDiv.appendChild(movieElement);
    childDiv.appendChild(yearElement);
    parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(parentDiv);

   //document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[i].innerHTML="<b>" + title + "</b><br>"; 
   //document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML= year + "<br>";    }
});
```

}

when this function is called second time the child divs are creating again though i've stated to first of all empty(in second line of sort function) the elements in the parent div and then create the child divs from the beggining.

```
function show(){
var z=document.getElementById("sortOrder").value;
sort(z);
//sort(Year)
//sort(title)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a typo, you're overwriting your parent div's id:

```
var parentDiv=document.createElement("div");
parentDiv.setAttribute("id","parentDiv");
parentDiv.setAttribute("id","childDiv"); // <--
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is parent div is also creating always as it is in the for loop so empty removes